# Is it possible to disable event cells in react big calendar?

Tags: reactjs

No event can be added in past date .i dont want to add event on past dates,is there is any function or logic or method in react big calender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Include the necessary file for React would be fine

```
react.production.min.js
react-dom.production.min.js
```

That's the very method been used in `code snippet` as below:

You can try the demo in-text:

```js
const App = () => {
const [val, setVal] = React.useState('some text');
const handleOnchange = e => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  setVal(e.target.value)
}
return (
  <div className="App">
    <input type='text' value={val} onChange={handleOnchange} />
  </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `npm start` to run the application because the `start` command runs the [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server).

This server handles live reloading and code transpilation, as well as many other tasks for you.

If you want more customization you can `npm run eject` to eject your app, but it isn't recommended. [Here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting/) are some alternatives to ejecting your app.

Otherwise, if it's hosting that you're worried about, you can have the `npm start` command run on deploy! I recommend [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) for some free quality hosting

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using react-script (which is part of the setup of create-react-app) you have everything for correct deployment at hand already. None of the mentioned manual steps are needed.

Instead, once you are ready to deploy (a version of) your app, run `npm run build`. This command will generated an optimized production build, bundling all your components and 3rd party libs into js files, together with the React and Webpack runtimes and put all that, including static content like images, into your build folder (location configurable). You can then copy that content to a machine with a webserver and start serving it from there, like any other web content.